# XSLT node counter in current document

Tags: xml, xslt, numbers, counter

I have the following xml document

```
<root>
    <TotalPeople>BLABLA</TotalPeople>
       <MoreTagsWithData/>
       <Person> 
           <id>bla-bla</id>
           <Name>John Smith</Name>
           <MoreTagsWithData/>
       </Person> 
       <Person> 
           <id>bla-bla</id>
           <Name>John Doe</Name>
           <MoreTagsWithData/>
       </Person> 
     </root>
```

I need to get the document

```
 <root>
<TotalPeople>2</TotalPeople> <!-- Needs to calculate how many "Person" tags -->
   <MoreTagsWithData/>
   <Person> 
       <id>1</id>  <!-- incrementing per each Person -->
       <Name>John Smith</Name>
       <MoreTagsWithData/>
   </Person> 
   <Person> 
       <id>2</id>
       <Name>John Doe</Name>
       <MoreTagsWithData/>
   </Person> 
 </root>
```

I tried XSLT template:

```
<!-- copy all file (I need to save the whole file since in reality it contains much more data -->

<xsl:template match="*|@*|text()">
              <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- indexing ids -->
    <xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


<!-- Piece I am not sure , it does not work -->

  <xsl:template match="TotalPeople">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:number level="any" count="/root/Person/id"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I need to calculate how many tags where in the document and modify special tag in my document with this value. I cannot create new document since real document contains a lot of information ans I need to maintain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the last template as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="TotalPeople">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/root/Person/id)"/>
        <!-- or just  select="count(/root/Person)" -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT stylesheets are designed to transform an input XML document to a separate output document, not to edit documents in-place. The above will produce the output document you requested, but it will not modify your existing document. At least, I don't know of an XSLT processor that will do that. Instead, you can delete your input XML file and rename the output XML to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the stylesheet below and transform your input XML doc to a separate output doc like @LarsH said.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TotalPeople">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(../Person)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:number count="Person"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, if you can use XSLT 2.0 you can try using `collection()`, `xsl:result-document` and `document-uri()` to overwrite your original file. It's kind of hacky and I would still recommend deleting the input XML and renaming the output XML.

**XSLT 2.0** (I only tested this with Saxon-HE 9.4.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="dir" select="'C:/Path/To/Doc'"/>
    <xsl:param name="file" select="'input.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection(concat('file:///',$dir,'?select=',$file))">
            <xsl:result-document href="{document-uri(current())}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TotalPeople">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(../Person)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:number count="Person"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Interesting ... I hadn't realized you could do that. If you overwrite the input document, is it guaranteed not to start overwriting until it's finished reading the original?

Comment: @LarsH - I'm not sure. Since it's not streaming I would think that the entire input would have to be read and in memory before processing/overwriting could begin. I've only done this twice and both times were for Stack Overflow answers. I didn't run into any issues when testing, but the data sets were small.